# Has SpaceX re-used a first stage twice yet?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, reuse, launch-vehicle, spaceflight-firsts

SpaceX has re-used a first stage once, several times now. Has it re-used the same first stage twice yet? If not, has a particular mission been named that will be the first second re-use?

Comment: More than one reflight will be done once Block 5 is operational. Will find a source later.

Comment: Update from the future: currently there are 7 times used block 5 boosters.

Comment: Just a small update. As of july 2021, they have reused boosters up to 10 times(10 flights, 9 reuses, for booster B1051). Including launching a crewed mission to ISS on a reused booster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. As of December 3rd, 2018, SpaceX successfully launched the same first stage ([B1046](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_9_booster_B1046)) 3 times and retrieved it twice. It supported the [Bangabandhu-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangabandhu-1) mission in May 2018, [Merah Putih](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telkom_Indonesia) mission in August (setting the current record for fastest turnaround time of 3 months), and then the [SmallSat Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHERPA_(space_tug)#Maiden_flight) mission on December 3rd 2018.

Comment: But I think there needs to be some more work on the translation; I don't think "have cash mission" and "Putin mission" and "Smallest mission" are what you mean.

Comment: Fixed mission identifications and added links. Welcome, Normen!

Comment: @RussellBorogove you're a "good samaritan badge" candidate, thanks!

Comment: Retrived it twice? Didn’t they land it the third time as well? https://spacenews.com/spacex-launches-all-smallsat-falcon-9-mission/

Answer (score 12):

No. The cores used are tracked at [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/wiki/cores), among other places. There are no plans to reuse a booster for a third time. There are 3 booster now that have been reused

- B1021- Will be displayed at cape, retired.
- B1029- Likely mothballed.
- B1031- This one just landed today, not sure of it's fate yet.

It will likely be a while before a second reuse is done, but they are slowly inching forward in that direction. I would guess one of the Block IVs, maybe B1042.

EDIT:

The current plan is to only reuse more then once the Block 5s. Currently SpaceX is working on expending all of the Block 3 and 4s in existence, to focus on Block 5, for a number of reasons. One of the most important is NASA wants to use Block 5 for the crewed missions, and needs 7 successful missions in a row before they will allow it to be used for manned missions.

Comment: I  knew the answer was no because I would have heard about it, but I'm really amazed at what the guys at Reddit have done...

Comment: I would like to mention, doing similars on the StackExchange would be closed/downvoted/deleted on most sites without major trickery and meta lobbying.

Comment: @peterh what does "doing similars" mean?

Comment: @uhoh sorry both comments seem a random word list to me now, but afterI woke up maybe I can decode them again

Comment: @uhoh: Doing the similar thing (i.e compiling a list, like Reddit did) would indeed be downvoted here. Makes sense: Reddit is a forum, this is a Q&A site.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto you should update your answer it looks like B1046 has been used twice and is being prepped to be used a third time

Comment: yay! time for an update?